# How do I duplicate CSV rows row_number times?

Tags: python, loops, csv

I am trying to use Python to generate a CSV file "distances" where I want to duplicate the rows of another file, "result" like this:

result.csv:

```
|ID |
|---|
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
...
```

distances.csv

```
|ID1 |ID2 |
|----|----|
| 1  | 1  |
| 1  | 2  |
| 1  | 3  |
| 2  | 1  |
| 2  | 2  |
| 2  | 3  |
...
```

Here is my Python code:

```
with open('distances.csv', 'wb') as ff:
    writer = csv.writer(ff, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    with open('result.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        reader2 = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

        for row in reader:
            for row2 in reader2:
                lst = []
                lst.append(row[0])
                lst.append(row[1])
                lst.append(row2[0])
                lst.append(row2[1])

                writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in lst])
```

For some reason it only duplicates the first row in result.csv

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many times should we duplicate each row from the source file? How do we obtain the column ID2 (or is it just a running count of how many time a particular row is being duplicated).

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, column ID2 is just the result from duplicating the rows IDs, so for row 1 as example, I want to duplicate all the IDs (including 1, I will remove that cases later). So imagine I have 100 rows, I want to duplicate each one 100 times.

Comment: Does it make sense to have a distances like (1,1), (2,2), etc.? they will always be equal to zero?

Comment: So If I'm understanding you each row is to be duplicated by the number of rows within the file. ID2 is a running count of the row per duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to make the repetitions on column `ID` in `distance.csv`:

```
from itertools import product
import csv


with open('result.csv', 'r') as fin, open('distance.csv', 'w') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    # skip header
    next(reader)

    buffer_ = [row[0] for row in reader]

    writer.writerow(['ID1', 'ID2'])
    writer.writerows(i for i in product(buffer_, repeat=2))
```

If you need more than 2 duplications: `'ID1', 'ID2',..., 'IDn'`, change the repeat value in `product` to `n`

Comment: Very good answer, but you could use a list comprehension instead of your first `for` and `writer.writerows(...)` instead of your second `for` to make it more efficient

Comment: That also worked! And it only gets the ID columns of the file, which is more accurate. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian  Thank you for noting

Answer (score 1):

Since the [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) is an iterator over the file, you can only go through it once. Try reading the rows into a list:

```
with open("result.csv", "b") as f, open("distances.csv", "wb") as ff:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer = csv.writer(ff, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    rows = list(reader)

    for row1 in rows:
        for row2 in rows:
            lst = row1 + row2
            writer.writerow(lst)
```